# ReferenceError: Cannot access 'players' before initialization

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Following suggestions from You (StackOverflow), I have rewritten my app to [several components]https://codesandbox.io/s/points-scored-forked-brnni?file=/src/components/ScoredPointsList.js:0-561

Now when I run yarn start, I get a reference error. After googling, I have tried with "everything" including:
changed from npm to yarn, changed in package.json ... but nothing seems to help.

How can I change the code to make it work?

```
import NewPointsScored from './components/NewPointsScored';
import ScoredPointsList from './components/ScoredPointsList';

function App() {
  const [scorerNumber, setScorerNumber] = useState('');
  const [totPoints, setTotPoints] = useState(0);
  const [players, setPlayers] = useState([]);

  const sortedPlayers = [...players].sort(
    (a, b) => a.scorerNumber - b.scorerNumber
  );
  const onePointHandler = () => {
    // eslint-disable-next-linex
    const players = [...players];

    if (scorerNumber.trim() === 0) {
      return;
    }

    const posit = players
      .map((player) => player.scorerNumber)
      .indexOf(+scorerNumber);
    if (posit !== -1) {
      setPlayers((players) =>
        players.map(
          (player, i) =>
            (i = posit ? {...player, totPoints: player.totPoints + 1} : player)
        )
      );
    } else {
      const newScorer = {
        id: Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000),
        scorerNumber: +scorerNumber,
        totPoints: totPoints + 1,
      };
      setPlayers([...players, newScorer]);
      setTotPoints(totPoints);
    }
    setScorerNumber('');
  };
  const twoPointsHandler = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('scored 2p');
  };
  const threePointsHandler = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('3p Made!');
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <NewPointsScored
        setScorerNumber={setScorerNumber}
        scorerNumber={scorerNumber}
        onOneP={onePointHandler}
        onTwoP={twoPointsHandler}
        onThreeP={threePointsHandler}
      />
      <ScoredPointsList sortedPlayers={sortedPlayers} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Thanks in advance
Regards
Peter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to modify players variable before it is being initialized , you can useMemo(which runs only if players value change) and modify sortPlayers after it is available and also you were trying to initalize players again that was causing issue

```
const sortedPlayers =useMemo(()=>{
  return players.sort(
    (a, b) => a.scorerNumber - b.scorerNumber
  );
},[players])
```

Full Code:

```
import NewPointsScored from './components/NewPointsScored';
import ScoredPointsList from './components/ScoredPointsList';
import {useMemo} from 'react'

function App() {
  const [scorerNumber, setScorerNumber] = useState('');
  const [totPoints, setTotPoints] = useState(0);
  const [players, setPlayers] = useState([]);

 const sortedPlayers =useMemo(()=>{
  return players?.sort(
    (a, b) => a.scorerNumber - b.scorerNumber
  );
},[players]) 


const onePointHandler = () => {
    const _players = [...players];

    if (scorerNumber.trim() === 0) {
      return;
    }

    const posit = _players
      .map((player) => player.scorerNumber)
      .indexOf(+scorerNumber);
    if (posit !== -1) {
      setPlayers((players) =>
        players.map(
          (player, i) =>
            (i = posit
              ? { ...player, totPoints: player.totPoints + 1 }
              : player)
        )
      );
    } else {
      const newScorer = {
        id: Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000),
        scorerNumber: +scorerNumber,
        totPoints: totPoints + 1
      };
      setPlayers([..._players, newScorer]);
      setTotPoints(totPoints);
    }
    setScorerNumber("");
  };
  const twoPointsHandler = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('scored 2p');
  };
  const threePointsHandler = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('3p Made!');
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <NewPointsScored
        setScorerNumber={setScorerNumber}
        scorerNumber={scorerNumber}
        onOneP={onePointHandler}
        onTwoP={twoPointsHandler}
        onThreeP={threePointsHandler}
      />
      <ScoredPointsList sortedPlayers={sortedPlayers} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

refer sandbox:

[image: Edit points-scored (forked)]

Comment: Thanks Goutham!unfortunately, still getting the  same reference error

Comment: Sorry, my bad. it works just perfect. Didn´t check your complete code, just copied the useMemo part....

Comment: In fact, it seems to be enough to change line 11-13 to: ```const scorers = [...sortedPlayers]``` and line 15 to ```const onList = scorers
      .map((scorer) => scorer.scorerNumber)
      .indexOf(+scorerNumber);```